Azure Dev Ops yaml pipeline run one target at a time
I want to run a pipeline that looks like this:
stages:
- ${{each environment in parameters.environments}}:
    - stage:
      displayName:  ${{ Replace(environment, '-', '_') }}
      dependsOn: ''
      jobs:
        - deployment: Run_script_${{ Replace(environment, '-', '_') }}
          environment: 
            name: '${{ environment }}'
            resourceType: 'VirtualMachine'
          condition: succeeded()
          strategy:
              runOnce:    
                deploy:    
                    steps:
                    - checkout:  none`

Where I can target one environment (in this case environment is an object parameter that can contain many environments and will run a stage for each environment) but each resource is targeted one at a time to run the work rather than in parallel. Is there a way to do this i'm missing?
I was hoping I could use condition: succeeded() in order to specify "if its the first job or if the previous job succeeded" but it seems that doesn't work. I'm not sure what else to try.
Thanks

Thanks for your update. If you just want to deploy to different VMs serially and have no order requirements, you can use the rolling strategy. If you have order requirements for the resources deployed, you need to use dependency at the job-level. See my update below if you need.

Turns out I was over complicating it, I can just use the "Rolling" deployment type and set maxParallel to 1.
          strategy:
              rolling:
                maxParallel: 1    


To run in parallel, you need to configure and pay for parallel jobs. For private projects,

When using Microsoft-hosted agents: You can get one free job that can run for up to 60 minutes each time.
When using self-hosted agents: For each active Visual Studio Enterprise subscriber who is a member of your organization, you get one additional self-hosted parallel job.

When the free tier is no longer sufficient, you can pay for additional capacity per parallel job.
Besides, ensure your environments don't have exclusive lock. The exclusive lock check allows only a single run from the pipeline to proceed. All stages in all runs of that pipeline that use the resource are paused. When the stage using the lock completes, then another stage can proceed to use the resource. Also, only one stage is allowed to continue.

Update
If you only want to deploy to your target VM one by one, you can use Rolling deployment strategy and set maxParallel to 1.
If you also want to control the order of deployment, you can use dependency at the job-level. Use one object parameter to define the environments, job dependency and resource.
In the following example, deployment to Env1 and Env2 can be done in parallel (if you have parallel jobs). Within each environment, deployment to different VMs is done sequentially. For example, when deploying to Env1, deployment to VM1 is done first and then to VM2.
parameters:
- name: EnvironmentList
  type: object
  default:
  - EnvName: Env1
    Resource:
    - Name: VM1
      Dependency: []
    - Name: VM2
      Dependency: Deploy_VM1
  - EnvName: Env2
    Resource:
    - Name: VM3
      Dependency: []
    - Name: VM4
      Dependency: Deploy_VM3

stages:
- ${{ each env in parameters.EnvironmentList }}:
    - stage: "Deploy_TO_${{env.EnvName}}"
      jobs:
      - ${{ each vm in env.Resource }}:
        - deployment: "Deploy_${{vm.Name}}"
          dependsOn: ${{ vm.Dependency }}
          environment:
            name: ${{env.EnvName}}
            resourceType: virtualMachine
            resourceName: ${{vm.Name}}
          strategy:
            runOnce:
              deploy:   
                  steps:
                  - script: echo "Hello world"



Thanks for answering. I actually want to achieve the opposite of this. I need my targets to deploy one at a time.
